# Is: $\sum_{k=-15}^{5}{(e^{\frac{i}{10}\pi })^{k}}$ equal to i or -i

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

This is what i did:
[image]

I hope it is readable, but to write everything in Latex is really painful.

My answer is i, and  it makes total sense to me, but some people disagree and say the answer is -i.

So if that is really the case can someone explain to me what I did wrong.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of providing an image of handwritten notes.

Comment: @DavidScholz: It will be interesting to you if you know that the number 8 in Persian is written as $\wedge$. This makes your suggestion bold.

Comment: According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+-15+to+5+%28e%5E%28%281%2F10%29pi+i%29%29%5Ek), your answer is correct.

Comment: @Mikasa: I don’t get what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $i$. Think about how the complex numbers you are adding are going around the unit circle in the complex plane. First consider the Real parts, for every point with a nonzero real part on the left there is a point added that has an equally long nonzero real part on the right, cancelling out all nonzero real parts in the sum. Now consider the Imaginary parts, for $k$ from $-15$ to $4$ you have a similar argument, where the imaginary part of each point above zero is cancelled out by the equivalently long imaginary part of a point below zero. Thus the only point in the sum that has not been cancelled out is the last point when $k=5$, which is the point $i$.